# k-nearest neighbour classifier using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, knn

I'm trying to implement my own kNN classifier. I've managed to implement something, but it's incredibly slow...

```
def euclidean_distance(X_train, X_test):
    """
    Create list of all euclidean distances between the given
    feature vector and all other feature vectors in the training set
    """
    return [np.linalg.norm(X - X_test) for X in X_train]

def k_nearest(X, Y, k):
    """
    Get the indices of the nearest feature vectors and return a
    list of their classes
    """
    idx = np.argpartition(X, k)
    return np.take(Y, idx[:k])

def predict(X_test):
    """
    For each feature vector get its predicted class
    """
    distance_list = [euclidean_distance(X_train, X) for X in X_test]
    return np.array([Counter(k_nearest(distances, Y_train, k)).most_common()[0][0] for distances in distance_list])
```

where (for example)

```
X = [[  1.96701284   6.05526865]
     [  1.43021202   9.17058291]]

Y = [ 1.  0.]
```

Obviously it would be much faster if I didn't use any for loops, but I don't know how to make it work without them. Is there a way I can do this without using for loops / list comprehensions?

Comment: What's `X_train`?

Comment: @Divakar You split the `X` into a training set and testing set. Imagine `X` is actually 200 rows of `x, y` values instead of only 2. This is then split into `X_train` and `X_test`.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a vectorized approach -

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
from scipy.stats import mode

dists = cdist(X_train, X)
idx = np.argpartition(dists, k, axis=0)[:k]
nearest_dists = np.take(Y_train, idx)
out = mode(nearest_dists,axis=0)[0]
```

Comment: I managed to use `spatial.KDTree` to implement it as well, and it's definitely faster, but when trying this [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neighbors/plot_classification.html) it still takes 40 seconds (was 240 seconds before). I cannot understand how `sklearn` can do this in 0.7 seconds?!

Comment: @user5368737 Well I am not aware of the internals of it. But if I have to throw a guess, I would say it might not be computing all distances and then throwing all but the nearest `k` ones, as we are doing here. But yes, I have seen `kDtree` being very fast compared to any Python/Numpy implemenations to do the same.

Comment: @user5368737 Just curious though - Did you by any change profile the proposed code and see which step is taking the most time on the larger dataset?

Comment: I did not use your code, but my own with `spatial.KDTree`, and there it's the querying I do (`X = Y_train[tree.query(X_test, k=k)[1]]`) that takes very long since `X_train.shape = (268288, 2)`. I do not know how to get this to be quicker unfortunately...